# no such element: Unable to locate element:

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to scrape the reviews content of https://www.tiaa.org/public/offer/products/life-insurance using below code

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(html_page)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="bv-hero-ALL-LIFE-INSURANCE"]/span[2]/span[2]""").click()
driver.implicitly_wait(20)
reviews_list = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('bv-content-item bv-content-top-review bv-content-review')
author = ''
summary = ''
product_family = ''

for div in driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="BVRRContainer"]/div/div/div/div/ol'):
    try:
        author = div.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="BVRRContainer"]/div/div/div/div/ol/li[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/h3').text
        summary = div.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="BVRRContainer"]/div/div/div/div/ol/li[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/p/text()').text
        product_family = div.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="BVRRContainer"]/div/div/div/div/ol/li[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/span/a').text
    except Exception:
        print(Exception)

if author and summary and product_family:
            single_item_info = {
                'author': author.encode('UTF-8'),
                'summary': summary.encode('UTF-8'),
                'insurance type': product_family.encode('UTF-8')
            }
            print(single_item_info)

driver.quit()
```

I am getting below error. Please guide or provide some pointers.

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="BVRRContainer"]/div/div/div/div/ol"}
  (Session info: chrome=57.0.2987.133)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.29.461591 (62ebf098771772160f391d75e589dc567915b233),platform=Windows NT 6.3.9600 x86_64)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `div` element with `id = BVRRContainer` is inside an iframe with index 0. You need to switch focus of Selenium to this iframe and only then it will be able to identify the review ratings.

To switch focus to this iframe, do this before your `for` loop

`driver.switch_to_frame(0)`